# relevent query to how to fetch public key from public key server

Tags: python, urllib

```
import urllib

response = urllib.urlopen('http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/')
print 'RESPONSE:', response
print 'URL     :', response.geturl()

headers = response.info()
print 'DATE    :', headers['date']
print 'HEADERS :'
print '---------'
print headers

data = response.read()
print 'LENGTH  :', len(data)
print 'DATA    :'
print '---------'
print data
```

This code enable me to see some webpage information and contents.
what actually i had query that how to fetch the public key from any public key server using python function.

Comment: Why do you keep asking the same question over and over again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254425/python-api-to-fetch-the-public-key-from-public-key-server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277281/how-to-fetch-the-public-key-from-public-key-server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299453/retrieve-key-from-key-server

Comment: Please edit and elaborate on your _first_ question.

Answer (score 4):

[This spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-shaw-openpgp-hkp-00) should help you along, and stop you asking the same question repeatedly :). Basically you need to perform an HTTP GET request to the key server. Most key servers work on TCP port 11371 so you need to ensure that your firewall will let you through.

For example, this URL will give you God's public key:

http://pool.sks-keyservers.net:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x1278A1862492D908&options=mr

The response is the key.

In python:

```
import urllib
f = urllib.urlopen('http://pool.sks-keyservers.net:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x1278A1862492D908&options=mr')
data = f.read()
print data

-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: SKS 1.1.0
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=NhFO
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Answer (score 1):

Use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-hkp

Python HPK client.

Usage example:

```
>>> from hkp import KeyServer
>>> serv = KeyServer('http://pool.sks-keyservers.net')
>>> serv.search('Dmitry Gladkov')
[Key 28DFA7EC RSA (Encrypt or Sign), Key 473C57D9 RSA (Encrypt or Sign)]
>>> serv.search('Dmitry Gladkov')[0].identities
[Identity Dmitry Gladkov (dgl) <dmitry.gladkov@gmail.com>]
```